# Create array from MYSQL data to show as checkbox values with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, prepared-statement

I have a MYSQL table containing usernames. I would like to pull this into an array and present it in a form as a series of checkboxes for users to select from.

The code below works for the first value in the table, and if I create an array (without pulling from the MYSQL table) then it shows all values.  What am I missing?

function:

```
function checkbox2( $name, $id, $label, $array_name = array() ) {?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p><?php echo $label; ?></p>
    <?php foreach ( $array_name as $value => $title ) : ?>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $name; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" <?php isset($_SESSION[$name]) ? checked($title, $_SESSION[$name]) : ''; ?>>
        <span class="checkbox-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
      </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>

function array_name() {
  // Connect to database
  $conn = db_connect();

  // Prepare and bind
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM usernames");

  // Execute and bind result;
  $stmt->execute();
  $response = $stmt->get_result();
  $array_name = $response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  return $array_name;
}
```

index.php

```
<?php $array_name = array_name(); ?> 
<form action="pageprocessresults.php" method="post">
<? checkbox2( 'user_name', 'user_name', 'Select name', $array_name ); ?>
<? submit('Go To Step 2 &raquo;'); ?>
```

Comment: Where do you call `array_name()`?

Comment: added array_name() call

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, the fetching from database is returning the first entry only since you are not looping on the db results.

Try implement pdo as follows

```
function array_name(){
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$yourhost.';dbname='.$yourdb.'', $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM usernames");
  $stmt->execute();
  while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $response[] = $res;
  }
  return $response
}
```

Comment: Use `fetchAll()` instead of the loop please

Comment: Thanks both for your answers.  Doing either, I get the following error: Array to string conversion for the line in my functions.php  file that corresponds to <span class="checkbox-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>

Comment: it means $title is an array, ...$response in array_name() is an associative array make sure you get indices correctly .. it better you print_r($title) and see output..